# jQuery more complicated selector vs. each element processing

Tags: jquery, performance, selector

I'm using ez-checkbox plugin, which simply wraps a checkbox into a div so checkboxes look better.

```
<div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
  <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off" class="ezmark ez-hide ez-init">
</div>
```

So I have many of these and I want check them all on click. Which of these click handlers is the best from the performance point of view:

First - find all inputs, filter out already checked ones, trigger click event for each element so that plugin done its job.

```
oPhotos
    .find('input')
        .not(':checked')
        .each(function() {
            $(this).click();
        });
```

Second - same as first, but we do the "checking" job ourselves.

```
oPhotos
    .find('input')
        .not(':checked')
        .each(function() {
            $(this)
                .prop('checked', true)
                .parent()
                    .addClass('ez-checked');
        });
```

Third - loop all checkboxes, if current is not checked - trigger the click.

```
oPhotos
    .find('input')
        .each(function() {
            if (! $(this).is(':checked')) $(this).click();
        });
```

Fourth - loop all checkboxes, if current is not checked - do the "checking" job ourselves.

```
oPhotos
    .find('input')
        .each(function() {
            if (! $(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this)
                    .prop('checked', true)
                    .parent()
                        .addClass('ez-checked');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Or let the library do all the checking and looping for you: `$(".ez-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").click();` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqkHJ/2/

Comment: The question is - is this kind of complicated selectors (".ez-checkbox input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)") are faster then processing each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run [performance tests](http://jsperf.com/selector-event-battle/2). Turns out that using more complicated selectors + filtering items using `.not()` + handling events instead of triggering them is the fastest option. The worst option is to loop all elements to filter them and trigger an event.